# What can cause UIAlertController actions to never be called?

Tags: ios, uialertcontroller, wkwebview

In crash reports I'm seeing `NSInternalInconsistencyException` get thrown from the `WKWebView` delegate methods for prompting JavaScript alerts, ie. "Completion handler passed to -[MyClass webView:runJavaScriptAlertPanelWithMessage:initiatedByFrame:completionHandler:] was not called".

Every `UIAlertAction` calls the `WKWebView` completion handler from its handler. The only explanation is that the alert is being canceled without invoking any action. `UIAlertView` had delegate methods for cases like this, but `UIAlertController` does not offer that level of control.

Has anyone devised a solution for this?

I've considered using the same technique Apple uses in `CompletionHandlerCallChecker` (in WebKit) to capture my own callback's failure to be invoked, and invoke the WKWebView's handler to prevent the spurious exception. Seems awfully kludgy, and I'm not yet sure it would work. I'd rather prevent this from happening in the first place.

Edit: I know that programmatically dismissing the alert controller produces this behavior, which is unfortunate, but I do not know the condition where iOS decides to dismiss the controller without user interaction.

Edit 2: For those requesting the code, it is really the minimum implementation:

```
- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView runJavaScriptAlertPanelWithMessage:(NSString *)message initiatedByFrame:(WKFrameInfo *)frame completionHandler:(void (^)(void))completionHandler {
  UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:message message:nil preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
  [alertController addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
    completionHandler();
  }]];
  [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Post the relevant code in your question.

Comment: Do you have a UIAlertAction for the Cancel button?

Comment: You ever find the solution to this? If not, how would you do CompletionHandlerCallChecker you mentioned?  I have the exact same issue where some other UI can come up and cause the alert to be dismissed and not told about only to cause this exception.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my kludgy but working solution:

```
class CompletionHandlerCallCheckerDefeater: NSObject {
  private var calledCompletionHandler: Bool = false
  private var fallbackHandler: () -> Void

  init(fallbackHandler: () -> Void) {
    self.fallbackHandler = fallbackHandler
  }

  deinit {
    if (!calledCompletionHandler) {
      fallbackHandler()
    }
  }

  func didCallCompletionHandler() {
    calledCompletionHandler = true
  }
}
```

In your delegate callback, use it like this:

```
let defeater = CompletionHandlerCallCheckerDefeater(fallbackHandler: completionHandler)
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .Alert)
alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title:"OK", style: .Default) { (action) in
    completionHandler()
    defeater.didCallCompletionHandler()
})
presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion:  nil)
```

Assign whatever is necessary to the fallbackHandler, it doesn't have to be the block passed in, it just needs to invoke the completionHandler with appropriate parameters. The "defeater" is destroyed when all references are released, that is, when the alert is destroyed, and it will call the fallbackHandler (which calls completionHandler) if didCallCompletionHandler was never called, thus avoiding the exception.